# list.append(obj) causes traceback - why is this?

Tags: python, django, list, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

Consider the following code:

```
for url in urls:
        obj           = HtmlInfo()

        obj.url       = url 
        obj.html      = hc.get_html(url)
        obj.tag_count = hc.get_num_tags(obj.html, 0, True)
        htmlinfos.append(obj)
```

where `urls` is a list of urls, and `htmlinfos` is initialized to an empty list like so -before the loop, of course:

`htmlinfos = [ ]`

Yet, for whatever reason, I get a `list-assignment index out of range` exception when I try to run this code.

What could be the problem with this? Note, my Python version is 2.7, and I'm using the latest stable version of Django (1.4, I believe)

**Update - Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxx/0/test/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'scrapper',
 'django_pdb')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django_pdb.middleware.PdbMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/share/nginx/www/xxx/private/xxx/views.py" in test
  44.         return HttpResponse("Dis be er bad query yo " + test_id )
File "/usr/share/nginx/www/xxx/private/xxx/views.py" in __get_html_list
  23.     return list

Exception Type: IndexError at /xxx/0/test/
Exception Value: list assignment index out of range
```

**Update - __get_html_list()**

```
def __get_html_list():
    hc = HtmlCounter()

    htmlinfos = [ ]

    #add more urls here for testing
    urls = [ '/usr/share/nginx/www/xxx/private/template/test/html_count_test.html' ]


    for url in urls:
        obj           = HtmlInfo()

        obj.url       = url 
        obj.html      = hc.get_html(url)
        obj.tag_count = hc.get_num_tags(obj.html)
        htmlinfos.append(obj)

    return htmlinfos
```

**Note**

originally `htmlinfos` was known simply as `list`, so I changed that before I posted this, reran it and I'm still getting the same error :/

**Update - get_html_tag_count()**

For brevity, I figured I may as well post this too, in case this could be related to the problem:

```
def get_num_tags(self, html):

        if reset:
            self.reset()

        current_index = 0

        for char in html:

            if (char == "<"):

                close_index = html[current_index:].find("/>", current_index)

                if close_index == -1:
                    break
                else:
                    ++self._tag_count

            ++current_index

        return self._tag_count
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error.  With the current information, all we can do is guess what is happening.

Comment: Such exception usually raises when you try to do something like list_object[k] = value when k >= len(list_object)

Comment: Updated, thanks. Is that enough info?

Comment: @aboutblank: Hmm, according to the traceback, the error happens in the line `return list` – maybe your web server needs to be restarted to use the current versions of the code?

Comment: It seems `list` is used as a variable name somewhere – this is a bad idea since it shadows the name of the built-in class.

Comment: What is `__get_html_list`? Can you post it?

Comment: Posted, thanks everyone! @SvenMarnach: I did end up restarting it, and  the error is still happening! For some reason I'm getting a `recursion depth exceeded` error as well in my `get_html_count` method, but not at the same time - the errors fluctuate between the two.

Comment: Also posted the `get_html_count` function just in case...

Comment: What are you using to run Django? uwsgi? Cycling errors generally indicate that some of the uwsgi (or similar) processes are using different code than the others. Make sure you actually restart uwsgi (or similar) and not just nginx.

Comment: I am restarting uwsgi...via `kill <pid>` and then `python manage.py runfcgi host=<host> port=<port> settings=<settings>`.

Comment: `++self._tag_count` isn't Python. It won't increment anything.

Comment: Please tone down the terminology - getting a traceback is much less severe than "getting a crash". If Python "crashes", it will exit abruptly giving you very little clue as the cause. Fortunately, crashes are very rare, and usually involve accessing of compiled C libraries. So you can see why the word "crash" is pretty alarming. In contrast, tracebacks are common, and usually leave a pretty good trail of breadcrumbs to locate the location of the error.

Comment: I'm still learning Python. Turned out it was due to my assumption that it allowed the pre-increment operator (I hadn't even thought of until @AnojiRox mentioned it). Anyway, I edited the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `++self._tag_count` and `++current_index` with `self._tag_count+=1` and `current_index+=1` respectively

`++var` works in most languages, but python isn't like most languages.